# Testing when returning components inside class methods

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

The below is my react code for which I am trying to write enzyme test case

```
getToolbarContent = () => {
  switch (this.props.botBuilder.selectedConsole) {
    case 'actions': {
      return this.getActionToolbar();
    }
    case 'usecases': {
      return this.getUsecaseToolbar();
    }
  }
}
// How to call ToolbarFloatingButton from method
getActionToolbar() {
  return (
    <div className="bot-toolbar-container">
      <ToolbarFloatingButton />
    </div>
  );
}
render() {
  return (
    <div className="bot-builder-toolbar">
      {this.getToolbarContent()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Enzyme:

```
it('call method getActionToolbar() and render ToolbarFloatingButton for actions', () => {
                const wrapper = shallow(<Toolbar {...defaultProps}/>);
                const getActionToolbarSpy = sinon.spy(Toolbar.prototype, 'getActionToolbar');
                expect(getActionToolbarSpy.calledOnce).to.be.false;
                wrapper.instance().getActionToolbar();

                //Trying to call ToolbarFloatingButton
                expect(wrapper.find(getActionToolbar()).dive().find(ToobarFloatingButton).to.be.length(1));
                expect(getActionToolbarSpy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
                getActionToolbarSpy.restore();
            });
```

The above one is my enzyme code where I am trying to mock the ToolbarFloatingButton inside getActionToolbar() but I am not able to mock up.

Comment: "but I am not able to mock up"... well, can you put more details, maybe a screenshot, the output of the tests.

Comment: Output:
<Toolbar>
       call method getActionToolbar() and render ToolbarFloatingButton for actions:
     ReferenceError: getActionToolbar is not defined